# How can I access a variable from my main.js file from within a required module?

Tags: requirejs, electron

I am starting to play around with Electron, and I was wondering how I can access a variable that lives in my main.js script from within a required script in the head of the main.js file.

Here is my dumbed down example:

**main.js :**

```
const Electron = require('electron');
const App = Electron.app;
const menus = require('./assets/js/menus.js'); //this is the required script!

let myVar = false;

App.on('ready', function({
   myVar = true;
})

//trying with module.exports
module.exports = {
   myVar
}
```

**menu.js :**

```
const Path = require('path');
const main = require(Path.resolve('./main.js'));

Main: [{
        label:'mainLabel',
        submenu:[{
            label:'subLabel',
            click:()=>{
                console.log(**main.myVar**)//should be true when i access it, its undefined like it doesn't exists:(
            }
        }]
}]
```

I managed to do what I want with getters and setters in main.js, but I feel this is not the best way to do this.

Any thoughts? Is there a way to include a script so that it has access to all variables and functions declared in the script including it?

Comment: Why `require(Path.resolve('./main.js'));` a simple `require('./main')` is enough the js part is preassumed by the node enviroment ? Also you can assign variables to the `App` variable and use them inside the main and renderer process. (Be aware that the render process makes a copy that does not get updated by itselfe)

Comment: Is menu.js running in the main process or a renderer process?

Comment: @pushkin Its running in the main process

Comment: @HansKoch Thanks for the heads up!